# Looking for a word that means "a lack of listening skills"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, phrasing

This is my first time here, and I am hoping this community can help me out.

The context is as follows:

> I witnessed a slow transition from awareness and excitement to
>   Wallace's "natural state" - irritability, discontent, and **a lack of
>   listening skills**.

Could anyone recommend a single word, or perhaps a better wording, for the bold text?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

Words like ***inattentive***, ***distracted***, ***distrait***, ***oblivious*** come to mind.

Since *lack of listening skills* as a phrase is broad—there are many ways in which someone can be a poor listener—you might want to just use the phrase itself.

Comment: "Inattentive" and "distrait" are both fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I witnessed a slow transition from awareness and excitement to Wallace's "natural state" - **irritable**†, discontent, and **inattentive**‡.

†Note: you may want to change *irritability* to *irritable*. *Irritability* is a noun that is a state of being, while *irritable* is an adjective that describes a noun's referent; in this case: Wallace's "natural state."

> **Inattentive** (adj.)
>
> 1. Of or pertaining to lack of attention; not paying attention; careless.
>
> > *He was **inattentive** in class and did not do well in his exams.*

#### ‡Alternatives:

> **Ignorant** (adj.)
>
> 1. Unknowledgeable or uneducated; characterized by ignorance.
> 2. (slang) ill-mannered, crude.

> **Unmindful** (adj.)
>
> 1. lacking awareness; oblivious
> 2. failing to remember or recognize something; heedless

> **Close-minded** (adj.) [alternately spelled: closed-minded]
>
> 1. unreceptive to new ideas or information; not open to any agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of listening skills is often due to *[self-absorption](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-absorption)*, in extreme cases *solipsism*:

> *self-absorption*
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 Preoccupation with one’s own emotions, interests, or
>   situation:
>
> *[solipsism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solipsism)*
>
> 1.1 The quality of being self-centred or selfish.

*ODO*

Comment: That's helpful, although solipsism would be taking it a bit far. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Sorry if I got carried away, namesake, but poor listeners are very much a _bête noire_ of mine.

Comment: I think this suggestion goes too far. It attempts to explain why someone is a poor listener, which is more than a term for the fact that someone is a poor listener.

Comment: You're right, but please look again at the context of describing Wallace, where I submit that it would work. Also, I don't like your dictionary definition of solipsism, which I understand as a disbelief in the existence of others or an outside world for them to be in. It's more radical than mere selfishness.

Answer (score 0):

If a person does not seem to understand what's being said, by either a lack of focus or an incapacity to actively listen, I would probably describe him or her as ***dense***.

From
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dense&defid=6219904 
"Not exactly stupid, the person can be book smart but can also be: thick headed, clueless, lacking common sense, unable to catch onto hints"